# Array of derived objects to array of base objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

There are multiple questions pretty similiar to this one with the difference that there `sizeof(Base) != sizeof(Derived)`. That won't work for obvious reasons (the subscript operator applied on the pointer is relative to the pointees size, not to the actual unterlying type). However, I was wondering whether this code would be correct or not:

```
struct Base
{
    int Data;
};
struct Derived : public Base
{
};
int main()
{
    static_assert(sizeof(Base) == sizeof(Derived), "Sizes are not equal");

    Derived Data[10];
    Base* Ptr = Data;
    Ptr[3].Data = 5;
}
```

Obviously, `Ptr[3]` won't access any half ripped `Base` instances anymore since the sizes are equal, but is the code still correct?

Comment: The language does not guarantee that the sizes are equal. If *you* guarantee that, then yes, it looks legal (doesn't mean you *should*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct (in the sense of well-defined, not necessarily sane) since the two classes are *layout-compatible* - they are standard-layout structs with the same non-static data members.

It's very fragile though; small changes to the classes could break the compatibility and give undefined behaviour.

Comment: Is it still well-defined if Base has some virtual methods that Derived overrides (with the size still staying the same)?

Comment: @Conclusio: no, if a class has virtual functions then it isn't standard layout.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we have a function that receives a `Derived`

```
double foo(Derived d);
```

Now consider a slight variation of your code:

```
Derived Data[10];
Base* Ptr = Data;
Base myB;
Ptr[3] = myB;
```

Essentially we have put a `Base` object into the `Data` array. We then call

```
foo(Data[3]);
```

Lo and behold we have tricked `foo` into receiving a `Base`

This is the reason you should not treat an array of Derived as an array of Base. It is not only the issue of size.

Comment: This has nothing to do with arrays.  You can do the same if you replace Data with a single Derived object.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider following lines:

```
Derived Data[10];
Base* Ptr = Data;
```

`Data` holds an address of first element of array. So, it is a pointer of type `Derived*`.
There is a static cast from `Derived*` to `Base*`. That means that code is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's obviously correct and I know that. But that wasn't the question, the core of the question was whether the subsequent subscript operator applied on the pointer is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

this is correct but not generally done because when pointer of derived class points to object of base, there is chance of data corruption.

Comment: But it is still correct. Anything else does not matter here :)